# TWRP app bricked my Huawei Y3 II phone and it refuses to be flashed again

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rom-flashing, recovery-mode, twrp, huawei

I have flashed my phone recovery mode official TWRP app with restarted the bootloader with ROM Toolbox Lite app, and then my phone didn't power up again and refused every single try to flash it with all the ROM on the internet. I went to authorization of Huawei and they said you will new a new board for the phone that will cost me the same as a new one. What should I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by flashing every partition  alone while the battery is off the phone and then hard reset.